# Google Speech To Text API not working in console

Tags: google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

{
"error": {
"code": 429,
"message": "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per minute' of service 'speech.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:XXXXXXXXXX'.",
"status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED",
"domain": "googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"quota_limit": "DefaultRequestsPerMinutePerProject",
"quota_metric": "speech.googleapis.com/default_requests",
"quota_limit_value": "0",
"service": "speech.googleapis.com"
}
}
]
}
}

Comment: getting the same type of issue when doing the most basic action of doing a listing of google business profile accoutns (when only one exists9)

Any news on this?